# How to disable "Recent" Windows 7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

When you right click on a taskbar icon such as notepad, it will popup a list called "Recent".

In my case, it is a large annoying list that I would rather have removed. How do I do this?

Comment: The answer is: right click on taskbar -> properties -> choose start menu tab, uncheck the checkbox says "store and display recently opened items in the start menu and the taskbar"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to modify your Windows 7 jumplist properties.

[image]

Comment: Jumplists don't get disabled altogether, just the best feature of them.

Comment: Important to note, as @matthews says. Jumplists do _not_ get disabled.

Comment: Thank you. I feel like an idiot for not seeing that.

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by pcmapbell will work, but that will turn jump lists off for **all** applications, not just notepad. Unfortunately there is no way to control this on a per-application basis. Out of curiosity, why is this an issue for you?

Comment: Obviously he's been looking at porn that he doesn't want to show up there.

Comment: ASCII porn? Interesting...

Comment: maybe notepad was mentioned just for covering the tracks ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option to remove individual entries via the "Remove from this list" right click action, for an individual item approach.

[image: right click action on notepad]

Comment: I was searching for this option recently, because I knew it from the RC of Win 7. In my final version, this does not work any more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the more detailed I found might be useful for you. http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/06/how-to-disable-recent-opened-documents-or-programs-in-start-menu-windows-7-tip/